# Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError

Tags: symfony, zabbix

Иногда при запросах время от времени возникает следующая ошибка:

> [2020-04-23 11:41:22] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError: "Error: Allowed
>   memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17844416
>   bytes)" at
>   /home/wgpavell/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemTrait.php
>   line 100 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError(code: 0):
>   Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 17844416 bytes) at
>   /home/wgpavell/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemTrait.php:100)"}
>   []

В редких случаях вариация ошибки бывает такой:

> [2020-04-24 16:56:25] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError: "Error: Allowed
>   memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10489856
>   bytes)" at
>   /home/wgpavell/symfony-blog/vendor/graze/guzzle-jsonrpc/src/functions.php
>   line 82 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError(code: 0):
>   Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 10489856 bytes) at
>   /home/wgpavell/symfony-blog/vendor/graze/guzzle-jsonrpc/src/functions.php:82)"}
>   []

Не могу понять в чем дело, но подозреваю этот участок кода у себя:

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
$maps = $cache->get('zabbix_maps', function (ItemInterface $item) use ($client) {
    $item->expiresAfter(3600);
    $response = $client->request('map.get', [
        "output" => "extend",
        "selectSelements" => "extend",
    ]);
    return $response->getResult();
});
```

С чем это может быть связано и как это можно вылечить? Использую Symfony 4.4.5, в качестве клиента [ZabbixClient](https://github.com/kamermans/zabbix-client). Мне нужно иметь данные о картах с заббикса, но вытаскивать их при каждом запросе долго, поэтому я кэширую данные на час. Возможно, я неверно это делаю? Ошибка возникает редко, с периодичностью 2-4 раза в день.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `php.ini` у вас есть параметр `memory_limit` который по умолчанию составляет 128 мегабайт. Попросту иногда памяти для хранения данных у вас требуется больше нежели выделено одному процессу. Это совершенно ни какая не ошибка с вашей стороны, естественно.

Соответственно решение проблемы банально донельзя. Увеличьте значение данного параметра.

p.s.
Достаточно хорошей практикой является создание отдельного файла с измененными вами параметрами, который вы потом помещаете в `conf.d` папку в настройках вашего `php`. По сути они перезаписывают стандартные параметры. Ну, а удобство в том что вы всегда знаете что именно у вас изменено вами и можете там же произвести дополнительные манипуляции с параметрами и ища их в `php.ini`

Comment: Как ни странно, в этом действительно была причина, ошибок за последние дни после увеличения памяти нет